# C++: cin.getline - no instance of overload function

Tags: c++, visual-studio, getline

I'am trying to write a line of text to a .txt file, but visual studio 2015 is giving me the following error.

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error (active)      no instance of overloaded function "std::basic_istream<_Elem, _Traits>::getline [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits]" matches the argument list    Studying    c:\Users\Klaas\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Studying\Studying\Studying.cpp 16

and

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2664   'std::basic_istream> &std::basic_istream>::getline(_Elem *,std::streamsize,_Elem)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'char *'    Studying1   c:\users\klaas\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\studying1\studying1\studying1.cpp  16

My source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ofstream myFile;
    string myText;
    myFile.open("sometext.txt");
    cout << "Write text to save to file: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(myText, sizeof(myText));
    myFile << myText;
    myFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I have done multiple searches and found answers such as including

```
cin.ignore();
```

above the

```
cin.getline
```

, but i just can't get it to work and i don't really understand what the error means, and i don't see why it thinks i'm trying to convert a string to char.

Any tips would be very welcome :)

Comment: it expects char*, not string

Comment: `sizeof(myText)` doesn't do what you think it does. Rather use `myText.size()`.

Comment: I saw, but im not sure how to make it expect a string, and im also not really sure how it expects a char* in the first place :(

Comment: std::getline() expects string, not std::istream::getline()

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, not gonna work for OP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using correct function. Instead of `cin.getline()` you should use

```
std::getline(cin, myText)
```

`cin.getline()` expects a pre-allocated `char*`, and your `myText` is not. It is also very hard to somehow manage to preallocate a buffer long enough for `std::basic_istream::getline()`, so this function is almost never useful at all.

Comment: Ah got it, thankyou so much for the help, it works now :)

Comment: I think he could also preallocate vector of chars and pass iterator to the beginning along with size of the vector to avoid overflows, but I think the solution is for extreme cases

Answer (score 0):

use `getline(cin,myText)` I honestly don't know why this problem exists or if it even is a problem but i know for a fact that this works.

Comment: *I honestly don't know why this problem exists* do not answer, than.

Comment: Thankyou so much :) it works now. is this something visual studio specific or am i just understand tutorials wrong that use cin.getline()?

Comment: you should probably forget that tutorials

Comment: @Lan_Tian Check [`std::istream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) vs [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

Answer (score 0):

<strike>See : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/</strike>

See : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline

The first parameter of this function getline must be a char *, not a string.

```
char myText[1024];
cin.getline( myText, sizeof(myText) );
```

As mentioned everywhere else, it's better to use the `std::getline`function:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

Comment: Please don't recommend that buggy and ambiguous reference. [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) does a way better job.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I didn't know the cplusplus website was problematic. I'll try the cppreference one then. Thanks!

Comment: @user4581301 : yes, it's a poorer solution than `std::getline` but I just wanted to inform what the error was in OP code. I'll edit my answer to stop my fall to hell, then...

Comment: That's not a fall to hell. The fall to hell starts with `#include <bits/stdc++.h> using namespace std;`